# I have a book (Books) I would like to store in SQLite

Tags: ipad, sqlite

I have a few million pages that I would like to store in sqlite.
The books are broken down into the following format.
   Bookseries
   BOOKName
   BOOKChapter
   BookParagraph
   BookLine
   BookNote
   BookComment.

The bookline will contain all the raw data that I will need to store. Some lines are more then 255 characters long. What I would like to know is how to store this data, Do I store it as a BLOB ? or TEXT?

The program stores Bible verses in 5 languages, hebrew russion arabic english and french.
SO I store this information as unicode and not ANSI

Answer (score 0):

If it's text, use the `TEXT` storage class and affinity; you can just declare the column as `TEXT` (among others).  Note that SQLite's classes and affinities are not length-specific.  So even if you said, `VARCHAR(255)`, it would still just be `TEXT`.  See the [Datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) page.

EDIT: The default [maximum](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length) string length is a billion characters.

Comment: yes but will i not have a problem with large amounts of text? like lets say 3 pages of characters ?

Comment: @ETT, no, that won't be a problem.